# Line 90:subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

I created below program to read comma separated data from file and then insert in to structures. There is a function called `struct person insert_into_struct(char line[])`. When I compile this in that function the in the last for loop `p.Id[j]=line[i];`got an error

```
line 90 error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  

struct person{
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    int  Id;
};

struct person insert_into_struct(char line[]);

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp1;
    fp1=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    char ch;
    char line[100];
    int i=0;

    struct person person_arry[100];
    int linenum=0;
    if(fp1==0)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while((ch=fgetc(fp1))!=EOF){

        switch(ch){
            case '\n':
                line[i]='\0';

                person_arry[linenum]=insert_into_struct(line);
                printf("line:%d, name: %s, address: %s, id: %s\n",
                    linenum,
                    person_arry[linenum].name,
                    person_arry[linenum].address,
                    person_arry[linenum].Id);
                linenum++;
                i=0;
                break;
            default:
                line[i]=ch;
                i++;
            }
        }

    }   
    return 0;
}

struct person insert_into_struct(char line[]){
    int i,j=0;

    // now we have to declare a temp structre to hold the seperated values
    struct person p;

    //now split the values one by one.
    //first copy the name from line[] into p.name
    for(i=0; line[i]!=',';i++, j++){
        p.name[j]=line[i];
    }
    i++;
    p.name[j]='\0';
    //printf("name=%s\n", p.name);

    //second copy the address in line[] to p.address[]
    for( j=0 ; line[i]!=',';i++, j++){
        p.address[j]=line[i];
    }
    i++;
    p.address[j]='\0';
    //printf("address=%s\n", p.address);

    // Erroneous line:
    //third copy the id in line[] to p.id[]
    for( j=0 ; line[i]!='\0';i++, j++){    
        p.Id[j]=line[i];
    }
    p.Id[j]='\0';
    //printf("Id=%s\n", p.Id);

    return(p);
}
```

Comment: You attempt to store the `Id` as a character string. Store it as an `int`. (This is a guess. I did not feel like counting to locate that fabled "line 90".)

Comment: You do not have to count it.Go to the struct person insert_into_struct(char line[]) then last for loop in that.

Comment: Well, I guessed right because that line contains `p.Id[j]` -- which is where you are "attempting to access `int Id` as a pointer, array, or vector".

Comment: Thank you.I got it.But is there a way to store p.Id by using line[i]?

Comment: Only if all id's in your source file are 1 digit long. Are you aware that `line[i]` is **only 1 character**?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your code to transform the string into number (atoi function):

```
   int atoi(char* str)
    {
        if(!str)
            printf("Enter valid string");

        int number = 0;
        char* p = str;

        while((*p >= '0') && (*p <= '9'))
        {
            number = number * 10 + (*p - '0');
            p++;
        } 
        return number;
    }
```

And then implement it like this:

instead of

```
 for( j=0 ; line[i]!='\0';i++, j++){
        p.Id[j]=line[i];
    }
```

write:

```
p.Id = atoi(line);
```

Comment: Are there any other solutions.Because I need Id as an integer.I have to sort Ids After this code.

Comment: I don't need int array per one struct. Normal int Id for per one strcut.

Comment: `atoi` is the right function to use, but with `atoi(line)` you read the integer from the start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way.
I created a variable called `char g[100]` then saved `line[i]` int to `g[100]`. Then converted `g[]` into `p.Id`.

```
char g[100];
for( j=0 ; line[i]!='\0';i++, j++){


         g[j]=line[i];
    }
    g[j]='\0';
    p.Id=atoi(g);
```